MAUI Dynamic Grid Column
I'm targeting the Windows platform, for now, using .net 8.
I have a view component with 4 components, placed using Grid in columns. In the middle, I put down a button with a command to swap my view. Kinda like this:

What I want after I click the swap button:

And swapped back when I clicked it again. It worked, but there's always some delay. Sometimes for 2 seconds, sometimes for almost 30 seconds.
Here's what I used:
ViewModel:
[ObservableProperty]
bool swap = false;

partial void OnSwapChanged(bool value)
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        Index0 = value ? 3 : 0;
        Index1 = value ? 2 : 1;
        Index2 = value ? 1 : 2;
        Index3 = value ? 0 : 3;
        Col1Horizontal = value ? LayoutOptions.End : LayoutOptions.Start;
        Col2Horizontal = value ? LayoutOptions.Start : LayoutOptions.End;
    });
    
}

[ObservableProperty]
int index0 = 0; // 0 || 3

[ObservableProperty]
int index1 = 1; // 1 || 2

[ObservableProperty]
int index2 = 2; // 2 || 1

[ObservableProperty]
int index3 = 3; // 3 || 0

[ObservableProperty]
LayoutOptions col1Horizontal = LayoutOptions.Start; // Start || End

[ObservableProperty]
LayoutOptions col2Horizontal = LayoutOptions.End; // End || Start

[RelayCommand]
void ExecuteSwap()
{
    Swap = !Swap;
}

View, inside the Grid:
<!--comp 0-->
<Grid Grid.Column="{Binding Index0}" ... some more properties>
    ...
</Grid>

<!--comp 1-->
<Grid Grid.Column="{Binding Index1}" ... some more properties>
    ...
</Grid>

<!--comp 2-->
<Grid Grid.Column="{Binding Index2}">
    ... 
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="{Binding Col1Horizontal}" ... some more properties>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Grid>

<!--comp 3-->
<Grid Grid.Column="{Binding Index3}">
    ...
    <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="{Binding Col2Horizontal}" ... some more properties>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Grid>

Inside every Grid shows some components to show data, and as you can see I changed the HorizontalOptions for some components, in the same function. All of the values changed when checked using breakpoint. The component using the HorizontalOptions changed as soon as the button was pressed. I couldn't find the cause for this delay.
Update: for more information, this component that I'm having trouble with is a part of a page. Inside that page, I also have some components that would get swapped the same way using the same button, where the other components would swap without any problem. The swap button is inside this bar component, and the command is inside this bar ViewModel. While the other component index properties are in the MainViewModel. I separated the ViewModel as it would be easier for data binding for each component.
I set the grid to invisible and put some labels as a test and it worked properly
<Label Grid.Column="{Binding Index0}" Text="index 0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
<Label Grid.Column="{Binding Index1}" Text="index 1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
<Label Grid.Column="{Binding Index2}" Text="index 2" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
<Label Grid.Column="{Binding Index3}" Text="index 3" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

Without removing the labels, the grids swapped as intended. For now, I'll keep the label, but I would like to have some explanation of why this happened.


What platform you are targeting on and also the .NET version? 2. Please help show col1Horizontal and col2Horizontal  which binds to the components and add it your XAML code. see how to create Minimal, Reproducible Example. As I test without these two properties, it swaps smoothly without any delay.


Thanks for responding. I'm targeting windows platform, using .net 8. I did some edit in the question, while still not including most of the view code

Thanks for your update, I still can't reproduce the delay after adding the relevant code. You can log a new issue on Github:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues .

Maybe have a look at the FlowDirection property, it might help you
